# how to connect lsm9ds1 to respeaker using mraa?

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi, microcontroller, sensors

I am new here, so please be patient with me

I have bought a respeaker device. I wanted to connect a bunch of sensors to it **(bme280,lsm9ds1,tsl2561)** but it turns out that I can't use the same raspberry pi code with it instead I have to use `mraa` and `upm`.

The `bme280` worked fine with the `upm` library but the `lsm9ds1` and `tsl2561` did not work.

So is there any `mraa` code for these sensors or I have to write it my self? and if so how can I get started?

note: all these sensors are from `adafruit`.

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

DIY
use the library that I have created https://github.com/omar7altawil/LSM9DS1-I2C